# How to arrange hexagons in CSS in a specific order?

Tags: html, css

I am very new to CSS, however I am getting a fair hang of it. I found out how to create hexagons and patterns, however I have trouble finding out how to do a specific order of them. What my order should initially [look like is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYIIf.jpg) (nevermind the background or the text underneath it)

I would appreciate if someone could explain me how to do this order and so it wouldn't get all messed up if browser window is too small or something.

Thanks.

Comment: Provide what you have so far

Comment: Alright, this is what I used for having hexagons (not mine as you can see):
http://dabblet.com/gist/3952030

But I thought, maybe I should use this, instead?
http://jsfiddle.net/mqyCb/59/

Comment: So in other words, you haven't done anything, you've just taken demos from other people? I'm sorry, I can't help you without you trying to help yourself. Understand what the demos do, you will then be able to reposition them

Comment: No, I have done a few things, but since I wasn't successful, I didn't mention them. However, I only tried it with [this](http://dabblet.com/gist/3952030) - the other one I found later and decided to seek help.
It seems the hexagons in that demo adjusts their size by the container they are in -  I tried putting the demo hexagons in two containers and it just resized and separated them. When I tried adding hexagons (by adding another <div> in html) and adding a line in CSS, it only lets me add two or one hex per row, but I need 4 hex in the first row and 5 in the second and 4 again in the last.